# Create JSON Array dynamically from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an object `A` as shown below.

```
var A = {
    "1": [ "1_1", "1_2", "1_3" ],
    "2": [ "2_1", "2_2" ]
};
```

Need to build a new array dynamically using js. Suppose
object A key should map to attribute text of Array AA and value should be to children as given below.

```
var AA = [
    {
        "text": "1",
        "state": "open",
        "children": [
            { "text": "1_1" }, 
            { "text": "1_2" }, 
            { "text": "1_3" }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "text": "2",
        "state": "open",
        "children": [
            { "text": "2_1" }, 
            { "text": "2_2" }
        ]
    }
];
```

This is my function but its not working as expected. Could someone pls help?

```
function constructJSONArr() {
    var A = {
        "1": [ "1_1", "1_2", "1_3" ],
        "2": [ "2_1", "2_2" ]
    };

    for (var key in A) {
        var tempArr = [];
        tempArr.push(key);
        for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
            return {
                'text': key,
                'state': 'closed',
                'children': A[key].map(function(child) {
                    return {
                        'text': child
                    };
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does not work? what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

When you return inside a function, the function ends and returns immediately. In your case, the `return` inside the for loop causes the function to return the 1st key object. To solve this, you need to create the objects and push them into an arr. You can return freely inside `Array.map()` because each iteration invokes a function.

**Fixed solution:**

Iterate with [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Get the `key`. Push a new object into `arr`. Use the `key` as the `text` property, the `state`, and `children`. To create the children get the array from the original object by the `key`, and use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate the child objects. Return `arr`.

```js
var A = {
  "1": ["1_1", "1_2", "1_3"],
  "2": ["2_1", "2_2"]
};

function constructJSONArr(A) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var key in A) {
    arr.push({
      text: key,
      state: 'closed',
      children: A[key].map(function(t) {
        return {
          text: t
        };
      })
    });
  }
  
  return arr;
}

var result = constructJSONArr(A);

console.log(result);
```

**ESNext solution**

Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get keys and respective values from the object `A`. Iterate the entries with two nested `Array.map()` calls. The 1st to create the outer object, and the 2nd to create the children.

```js
const A = {
  "1": ["1_1", "1_2", "1_3"],
  "2": ["2_1", "2_2"]
};

const constructJSONArr = (obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).map(([text, children]) => ({
    text,
    state: 'closed',
    children: children.map((text) => ({
      text
    }))
  }));

var result = constructJSONArr(A);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate through the object and `Array.map` to create the new array.

```js
var A = {
  "1": ["1_1", "1_2", "1_3"],
  "2": ["2_1", "2_2"]
};


var transformed = Object.keys(A).map(key => {
  return {
    text: key,
    state: "open",
    children: A[key].map(value => {
      return {
        text: value
      };
    })
  };
});

console.log(transformed);
```